# How to create a security scan for compute engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I use my dns provider to point my domain to a compute engine IP. Then tried to use compute engine security scanner to scan on that domain and IP address.

It returns:

> You do not have permission to scan one of the starting URLs

Anyone know how to properly do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure that you are not using the ephemeral IP, but a **static** one and that you are not trying to perform a Compute Engine scan making use of a App Engine scanner ( in this case you would get the very same error message).

> In order to use the Compute Engine scanner your project need to be whitelisted since it is a closed alpha feature. A new tab will appear in the Compute Engine menu.

Check as well that the domain is mapped to this IP only and that this IP has been reserved in the very same project (same organization is not enough)
and that is publicly available and pointing to the right IP:

```
$ nslookup pagetoscan.com
```

Moreover you have to make sure that the account that is trying to perform a security scan have one of the two following [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/security-scanner/docs/access-control#predefined_iam_roles):

- **cloudsecurityscanner.runner**   Read-only access to scan and scan run, plus the ability to kick off scans
- **cloudsecurityscanner.editor**   Full access to all Cloud Security Scanner resources

, but if you are owner of the project it is granted per se.

I hope that you are experiencing one of this issues, otherwise you can check the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/security-scanner/docs/scanning-compute-engine).